# c++ DirectX function Present() not working

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I'm working on simple graphic library in DirectX. I use Dx 9 because I'm pretty new in it and I have found a good programming book written for 9th version. Anyway, I can't get anything on the screen because Device's function **Present()** returns **E_FAIL** code 0x80004005 (which what I've read mean 'Unspecified failure'). 
I've also checked all Dx functions used in program and none of them returns fail (except Present() obviously).

The program works fine if I comment line **kAnimation.Render()** from main.cpp

Here's the causing problems part of code:

main.cpp:

```
//...
if(FAILED(g_pkD3DDevice->BeginScene())) return ErrorBeginScene;

kAnimation.Render();

if(FAILED(g_pkD3DDevice->EndScene())) return ErrorEndScene;

HRESULT hr;
hr = g_pkD3DDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); //Returns E_FAIL
if(FAILED(hr)) return ErrorPresent;
```

Animation.cpp:

```
#define D3DFVF_MYVERTEX (D3DFVF_XYZRHW|D3DFVF_DIFFUSE|D3DFVF_TEX1)

Error Animation::Render()
{
    //...
    //This is what contain fX[4] and fY[4] and other variables while debugging
    //float fX[4]
    //float fY[4]
    //fX[0] = -16; fX[1] = 16; fX[2] = -16; fX[3] = 16;
    //fY[0] = 16; fY[1] = 16; fY[2] = -16; fY[3] = -16;
    //m_iCellHeight = 32
    //m_iCellWidth  = 32
    //m_iTextureWidth = 128
    //m_iTextureHeight = 128
    //kTextCoord.Left = 1/128; .Right = 33/128; .Top = 1/128; .Bottom = 33/128;

    Rect kTextCoord = GetUV(CellID(0,0));

    Vertex kVertices[] =
    {   //x, y, z, w, color, texture coord (u, v)
        { fX[2], fY[2], 0, 1.0f, iColor, kTextCoord.Left, kTextCoord.Top},
        { fX[3], fY[3], 0, 1.0f, iColor, kTextCoord.Right, kTextCoord.Top},
        { fX[1], fY[1], 0, 1.0f, iColor, kTextCoord.Right, kTextCoord.Bottom},
        { fX[0], fY[0], 0, 1.0f, iColor, kTextCoord.Left, kTextCoord.Boottom},
    };

    g_D3DDevice->SetTexture(0, m_pkD3DTexture);
    g_D3DDevice->SetFVF(D3DFVF_MYVERTEX);
    if(FAILED(g_D3DDevice->DrawPrimitiveUP(D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN, 2, kVertices, sizeof(Vertex)))
    return ErrorDrawPrimitive;

    return NoError;
}

Rect Animation::GetUV(CellID kPosition)
{
    Rect kUVRect;
    kUVRect.Left =  (1 + ((1 + m_iCellWidth) * kPosition.x)) / m_iTextureWidth;
    kUVRect.Right = (1 + ((1 + m_iCellWidth) * kPosition.x) + m_iCellWidth) / m_iTextureWidth;
    kUVRect.Top =   (1 + ((1 + m_iCellHeight) * kPosition.y)) / m_iTextureHeight;
    kUVRect.Bottom =(1 + ((1 + m_iCellHeight) * kPosition.y) + m_iCellHeight) / m_iTextureHeight;
    return kUVRect;
}
```

Rest you need:

```
class Rect
{
public:
    float Left;
    float Right;
    float Top;
    float Bottom;
};

//Position of single cell in animation texture
class CellID
{
public:
    unsigned long x;
    unsigned long y;
};
```

My operating system is Windows 7 Ultimate. I'm using VS c++ 2010
If you would like to see entire solution there's link: http://speedy.sh/CmBRb/ConWinLib.rar
(It's a bit different than that because I wanted to make code as short as I could)

Thank you for any help!

**EDIT**

Answering to your questions:

@tbridge The Device should be good because I created few small programs before and they were working prefectly. But anyway there's the code:

```
//...
g_pkD3D   = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS kPresentParams;
unsigned long iDeviceType = D3DDEVTYPE_REF; //I have already checked D3DDEVTYPE_HAL and it doesn't work either

ZeroMemory(&kPresentParams, sizeof(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS));
kPresentParams.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;


D3DDISPLAYMODE kCurrentMode;

if(FAILED(g_pkD3D->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &kCurrentMode)))
    return ErrorGetAdapterDisplayMode;

kPresentParams.Windowed = true;
kPresentParams.BackBufferCount = 1;
kPresentParams.BackBufferFormat = kCurrentMode.Format;

if(FAILED(g_pkD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, (D3DDEVTYPE)iDeviceType, hWindow,
     D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &kPresentParams, &g_pkD3DDevice)))
return ErrorCreateDevice;

g_pkD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);
g_pkD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);
g_pkD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
g_pkD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
g_pkD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRSDESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);

g_pkD3DDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
g_pkD3DDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);

c
```

Comment: How is the device initialized? Post some code?

Comment: You should consider using .zip file instead of .rar file.

Comment: I've download an review the code, it has lots of memory access errors, you comment out lots of code, please give the original code.

Comment: Sorry, but the book was very bugged. I've fixed most of them but some still exist. I'm stuck at this one and I can't go further. The comments are because of previous bugs - I left lines if they might be useful. I hope it's not such a big problem.

Comment: Can you give the code which cause the Present error? I only got accesss voilation error with the code above.

Comment: I thought that is the code which cause the error. You can download rest. But I don't know why do you get access violation error - I don't get any of theese. Could you tell me where does it break?

Comment: line 107, mAnimation.cpp

Comment: Right, forgot to remove. But this doesn't change anything: it just return component from mrTemplateSet